# Is Hfeed class for all pages needed

Tags: posts, html, seo

Hey there :) I'm trying to fully understand the Hfeed class used in underscores.me themes. I'm developing a site on most of the underscores structure, but I can't figure out if I can remove the hfeed class. Should I only use the Hfeed class on my news posts, case posts and customer posts and remove the class from all other pages?

Hope someone got some info / input on this.

Cheers.

Comment: Did you ever come to a conclusion on this? Thanks.

Comment: I toke my own conclusion after reading up on hfeed to just remove it from the site in generel. I added schema.org to the news and I'm hoping it will do just fine:P But, I would suggest you to read up on the hfeed class, and maybe you can find a better conclusion. Have a nice night!